# Can't Start 64-bit AMI on t1.micro instance on AWS

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, amazon-ami

I created a custom AMI based on the Ubuntu 11.10 64-bit AMI from Amazon. When I try to start it up, I get an error:

```
ec2-run-instances -t t1.micro ami-c0b368a9 -k showcase -z us-east-1a

Client.InvalidParameterValue: The requested instance type's architecture (i386) does not match the architecture in the manifest for aki-825ea7eb (x86_64)
```

When I look in the FAQs here: http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/Instance_Types_and_Architectures.html

it says "All instance types can run 64-bit AMIs."

How can I start a 64-bit AMI?

I'm running ec2-api-tools 1.5.2.5 and ec2-ami-tools 1.3-45758 on OSX.

Any help would be much appreciated.

****UPDATE:** I created the AMI incorrectly, when registering an AMI from a snapshot, I needed to provide --architecture x86_64 to the ec2-register command.**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your ami-c0b368a9 is 32-bit.

For some reason, it was registered with a 64-bit kernel image (aki-825ea7eb).

Your AMI and AKI need to match in architecture.

You could simply specify a 32-bit kernel to run with the 32-bit AMI, but it's probably best to build and register the AMI correctly.

Comment: Thanks after thinking about your answer "register the AMI correctly" I found that I can specify the architecture on the command line for ec2-register:


> ec2-register -s snap-56b3ca2b --kernel aki-825ea7eb --architecture x86_64 --description "Web2py 1.99.7 base install with nginx, uwsgi, rabbitmq 2.8.1" --name "web2py-1.99.7_nginx_uwsgi_v2"